# xhtml link can't be opened and file was not found

Tags: xhtml, anchor

Hey guys I am new to web languages. I was just trying out the link syntax of xhtml and everything appears smooth until I clicked on the link and it tells me that my file is not found, either moved or deleted.  It's really basic however I checked word for word that the syntax is correct, and nothing on the internet answers it hope someone could help.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>This is title</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <a href=="https://www.google.com/">click me.</a>
    <br>
    <a href=="second.html">This will link to the second page</a>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try making it a single equal sign instead of two. `=` vs `==` in the `<a href ... >` tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edited Links

```
<a href="https://www.google.com/">click me.</a> <br><a>
<href="second.html">This will link to the second page</a>
```